# Sort String column which has numbers and Alphabets( Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I want to sort a string column which can include both numbers and alphabets.

**SQL Script:**

```
select distinct  a.UoA, b.rating , b.tot from omt_source a left join  
wlm_progress_Scored b
on a.UoA = b.UoA 
where a.UoA in (select UoA from UserAccess_dev
where trim(App_User) = lower(:APP_USER))
order by 
  regexp_substr(UoA, '^\D*') ,
  to_number(regexp_substr(UoA, '\d+'))--);
```

**Output I'm currently getting:**

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
10 
11 
12 
13 
14 
15 
16 
17 
18 
19 
20 
23 
26B
26A
27 
28 
30 
31 
32 
33 
34B
34A
```

But, I want `26` and `34` to be in this order

```
26A
26B
34A
34B
```

Any suggestion will be much helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first order by clause ensures that the primary sort order is based on the numerical component of the UoA field, then your second order clause could actually be just the UoA field itself. I.e.

```
    order by 
      regexp_substr(UoA, '^\D*'), UoA;
```

Comment: Thanks Much I just used this and got it working    -----                                             
  order by 
  regexp_substr(UoA, '^\D*') nulls first,
  to_number(regexp_substr(UoA, '\d+')),--);,
  regexp_replace(UoA, '^\D*\d+')  NULLS FIRST;

Comment: @Praveen . . . If this solves your problem you should accept it.